# AzMan authorisation in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-core, authorization, roles

How can I authenticate users in asp.net core against Active Directory with roles and task managed through what was known as Authorisation Manager(AzMan)?

I used this with form authentication in my asp.net 2.0 app which I'm now rewriting using asp.net core 1.0.

It is not just about authentication against Active Direcctory. AzMan can manage roles and task access rules.

Many thanks in advance

Bertrand

Comment: It is not just about authentication against Active Directory. Are you familiar with AzMan?

Comment: Sorry, it is my bad understanding.